# Discord.js client.token returns "null" and doesn't work

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm having a problem with discord.js: "client.token" doesn't work, even though it's provided in documentations. Well, I can just copy-paste the actual token like I did before, but let's say I want to make my code open-source. My bot is hosted on Heroku and I heard there was a way to hide your token and I even tried to do it, but seems like it doesn't work when you run your bot locally - only when bot is on hosting. And sometimes I just need to run my bot locally, but it's inconvenient to always change from Heroku hidden token to actual "string" token. Is there a universal way to hide one's token?

I've tried writing "client.user.token" (silly, but I had to try) and "var" instead of "const" (see the code below). Also tried to console.log it - the output was "null".

```js
const token = client.token;

console.log(token); // "null"!

// ...some other code stuff

client.login(token);
```

The bot is expected to read the token and login, but I get this error: `(node:2080) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: An invalid token was provided.`

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is returning `null` is because you haven't *provided* a token in the first place, `client.token` returns the token the bot is actively logged into, which you need to provide. `client.token` is set when you run `client.login()` with your token found at your Discord developer portal

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.env** file which will keep your token hidden from anyone.

**Steps:**

1. Open your bot folder.
2. Make a new file in your code editor called ".env"
3. Write: token: "INSERT TOKEN HERE"
4. Open your main file and type in client.login function: "process.env.token"
   And that's pretty much it.

[If you didn't understand something click me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a782N.jpg)

Sorry for this poor explanation, I'm kind-of tired so yeah just deploy it to Heroku and it'll work both locally and Heroku.

Comment: I still get the same error. Files are in the same folder. Also all the code is on GitHub, so I added the .env file to .gitignore. console.log says undefined.

**.env file:** `token: "<your token value>"`

**main file:** `client.login(process.env.token);`

Comment: .env files do not use JSON type. It should be `TOKEN=key`

Comment: @OHSHIET The comment you left here had what appeared to be an actual token in it. I've edited that out. If that was an actual security token, you should assume that it's compromised and invalidate it. If it helps to identify it, there were several consecutive `A` characters.

Comment: thank you. I don't remember what it was now but I just replaced some characters in my token and seems like you should never do that anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting up your .env file wrong. It should be

```
KEY=variable
```

For example:

```
#.env
TOKEN=m1i1m312im

#app.js
token = process.env.TOKEN
client.login(token)
```

Comment: still the same error and undefined when I'm trying to console.log the token.

Comment: It should be `token = process.env.TOKEN` `client.login(token)` (and then in .env) `TOKEN=13412`